# Regular expression problem, skipping unkown amount of matches?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am using c# but its basically not really important, my question is: is it possible, only with regular expression skipping matches?

my regex was

```
Text = Regex.Replace(Text, @"\[code1\]((.|\n)*?)(\<\/span\>) ", "<span class='spanTest'>$1</span>");
```

but the problem with this, is greedy... allways gets the first match of the closing span

I have a string similar like this:

```
[code1]test string bladibla[code2]code2 string</span> [code3] code3 string [code1]&nbsp; </span></span> end of the span string </span>
```

and my ending result should be something like:

```
<span class="spanTest">test string bladibla[code2]code2 string</span> [code3] code3 string [code1]&nbsp; </span></span> end of the span string </span>
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that substrings starting with "[code]" and ending with "</span>" can be nested inside each other, and you are trying to find matching pairs of them, the answer is no. Regular expressions can't match nested patterns, it's one of their theoretical limitations. (I know that's not a solution, but it is permission to stop banging your head on this particular wall.)

Comment: Cheers:) I just found a nice blog entry, in case if somebody would have the same problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow you. Your regex is definitely *not* greedy (`*?` is a lazy quantifier), so it will match from `[code1]` to the closest `</span>` it finds, just as in your example.

However, it will also match from the second `[code1]` in your sample until the following `</span>`. Is it this behaviour you're trying to prevent? If so, what is the difference between the two cases? Do you only want to match the first occurrence, or do you only want to match it at the start of the string, or...?

Finally, instead of `((.|\n)*?)` you can write `(.*?)` if you specify `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Comment: I thing in graph theory means greedy, that matching the first occurence of the string, in this case a first closing span. Which is not the behaviour that I want to achieve. If you see my "starting" string and the (desired)output string, then its clear, that I want a match with the last occurence of the closing spans. Therefore I can avoid the "nestation" problem. 

And why is a usage of RegexOptions.Singleline is better then a pure regular expression? I dont see the point, besides its more typing.

Comment: Interesting. Well, in regular expressions "greedy" means "try to match as much as possible". So if all you want is to match from the first `[code]` to the last `</span>`, just drop the `?` after the `*`.

Comment: About `RegexOptions.Singleline`: Usually in regexes, the dot matches any character except newline; and nearly all regex flavors (except JavaScript) have a "dot matches all (including newlines)" option. In .NET, it's turned on via `RegexOptions.Singleline` which is more explicit than the cryptic `((.|\n)*)` construct, especially if it turns up more than once in the regex.